# Error incomplete type is not allowed, simple array C

Tags: c

I am building a program that should find a char in a string according to lower case alphabet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
                if (str[i] < 48 || str[i] > 57)
                break;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

I've never had this problem before and I used incomplete types (arrays and strings) hundered situations.
Anyway, **Visual Studio 2012** alerts about **incomplete type**:

```
1   IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed    Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C\C\main.c  6   7   C
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You have not defined the length of the string (char array)

Comment: "I used incomplete types (arrays and strings) hundered situations" -- Not likely. Note that `char str[]` as a parameter is not an incomplete type; it is equivalent to `char* str` in that context. (If you were to replace `char str[]` with `char* str` above, that would be undefined behavior and the program would probably crash.) And `char str[] = "abc";` is also not an incomplete type -- the array size (4) is determined from the initializer.

Comment: `if (str[i] < 48 || str[i] > 57)` this sort of thing is useful for entries in "Obfuscated C" contests but is awful practice otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must specify array size when you declare an array without initializer.

```
char str[SIZE];  
           ^Size of your array.
```